# Optional dependency not satisfied: install igraph and leidenalg to use the selected feature

Tags: python, anaconda, runtime-error, networkx

I was trying to run the following [example](https://cdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/cd_algorithms/algs/cdlib.algorithms.leiden.html) from the cdlib documentation:

```
from cdlib import algorithms
import networkx as nx

G = nx.karate_club_graph()
coms = algorithms.leiden(G)
```

But I got the following error:

```
Optional dependency not satisfied: install igraph and leidenalg to use the selected feature.
```

So, then I ran:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install igraph
!{sys.executable} -m pip install leidenalg
```

In order to install the selected packages,
thinking it would solve the problem.
However, I got the same error yet again.

Can you help me fix this?

EDIT:
I found this [issue](https://github.com/GiulioRossetti/cdlib/issues/77), showing the same problem. Apparently restarting the kernel fixes it.

Now I get the following `DeprecationWarning` instead:

```
DeprecationWarning                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-6636976ddbf9> in <module>
----> 1 from cdlib import algorithms
      2 import networkx as nx
      3 G = nx.karate_club_graph()
      4 coms = algorithms.leiden(G)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cdlib/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from cdlib.classes.node_clustering import NodeClustering
      2 from cdlib.classes.edge_clustering import EdgeClustering
      3 from cdlib.classes.fuzzy_node_clustering import FuzzyNodeClustering
      4 from cdlib.classes.attr_node_clustering import AttrNodeClustering
      5 from cdlib.classes.bipartite_node_clustering import BiNodeClustering

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cdlib/classes/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .node_clustering import NodeClustering
      2 from .edge_clustering import EdgeClustering
      3 from .fuzzy_node_clustering import FuzzyNodeClustering
      4 from .attr_node_clustering import AttrNodeClustering
      5 from .bipartite_node_clustering import BiNodeClustering

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cdlib/classes/node_clustering.py in <module>
      1 from cdlib.classes.clustering import Clustering
----> 2 from cdlib import evaluation
      3 import networkx as nx
      4 
      5 try:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cdlib/evaluation/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .fitness import *
      2 from .comparison import *
      3 from .fitnessranking import *
      4 from .comparisonranking import *

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cdlib/evaluation/fitness.py in <module>
      1 import pquality as pq
      2 import networkx as nx
----> 3 from cdlib.utils import convert_graph_formats
      4 from collections import namedtuple
      5 import numpy as np

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cdlib/utils.py in <module>
      1 from contextlib import contextmanager
      2 try:
----> 3     import igraph as ig
      4 except ModuleNotFoundError:
      5     ig = None

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/igraph/__init__.py in <module>
      6 __license__ = "MIT"
      7 
----> 8 raise DeprecationWarning("To avoid name collision with the igraph project, "
      9                          "this visualization library has been renamed to "
     10                          "'jgraph'. Please upgrade when convenient.")

DeprecationWarning: To avoid name collision with the igraph project, this visualization library has been renamed to 'jgraph'. Please upgrade when convenient.
```

Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using:

```
!{sys.executable} -m pip install python-igraph
```

Instead of:

```
!{sys.executable} -m pip install igraph
```

Solves the issue.
This is because `igraph`(renamed to `jgraph`) is a different package from the well-known `python-igraph`.